# Cognito and MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, multi-factor-authentication

We would like for username and password to be asked every time but not the MFA. I see there is an option to remember the device in Cognito. Is it possible that MFA can be prompted less frequently but with the login credentials every time?

If remember device suppresses the MFA prompt, how long does it suppress it for?

Comment: To get MFA code in email instead of phone you have to implement that yourself using Lambda for the Cognito "Define Auth Challenge", "Create Auth Challenge" and "Verify Auth Challenge" triggers.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks. If remember device suppresses the MFA prompt, how long does it suppress it for?

Comment: I don't use "remember device" which is why I didn't post a full answer to your question, just a comment.

Answer (score 3):

> If remember device suppresses the MFA prompt, how long does it
> suppress it for?

**Till the device is remembered.**

Depending upon how you configure `Cognito Userpool` to remember devices and opting to suppress MFA for remembered devices, the following are the possibilities.

- **Always** : In this case the user will be presented a MFA only once i.e. the first time they sign in from a new device.
- **User Opt In**: In this case the user decides if he/she wants the particular device to be remembered or not. (Once remembered, the MFA is suppressed from the same device until the user opts out to remember the device.)

For the `SRP` flow to work, the client must have the correct `deviceKey`, `deviceGroupKey` and `randomPasswordKey`. If the client doesn't provide this information, then it would be challenged with MFA. If the user uses a browser in `incognito` mode or clears the `LocalStorage`, it would be presented with the MFA challenge.